# pascal adding tedit text to record

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I am having problems with adding text I have entered into a tedit, into an record.
Here is the code i currently have:

```
procedure TForm7.AddNewQuestionClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
   w: integer;
   QuestDesc, QuestAnsr: string;

 begin
   NewQuestID.text:=(GetNextQuestionID); //Increments QuestionID part of record
   w:=Length(TQuestions);  
   SetLength(TQuestions, w+1);
   QuestDesc:= NewQuestDesc.text;
   QuestAnsr:= NewQuestAns.text;
   TQuestionArray[w+1].Question:= QuestDesc; // Error on this line (No default property available)
   TQuestionArray[w+1].Answer:= QuestAnsr;

 end;
```

Here is the record I am trying to add to:

```
 TQuestion = record
  public
    QuestionID: integer;
    Question: shortstring;
    Answer: shortstring;
    procedure InitQuestion(anID:integer; aQ, anA:shortstring);
 end;  

TQuestionArray = array of TQuestion;
```

Any help solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a few things. You've declared a procedure to help initialize a new question - you should be using it.

This should get you going:

```
type
  TQuestion = record
    QuestionID: integer;
    Question: ShortString;
    Answer: ShortString;
    procedure InitQuestion(anID: Integer; aQ, aAns: ShortString);
  end;

  TQuestionArray = array of TQuestion;
var
  Form3: TForm3;

var
  Questions: TQuestionArray;

procedure TForm7.AddNewQuestionClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(Questions, Length(Questions) + 1);
  Questions[High(Questions)].InitQuestion(GetNextQuestionID, 
                                            NewQuestDesc.Text,
                                            NewQuestAns.Text);
end;
```

If you really want to do it individually setting the fields:

```
procedure TForm7.AddNewQuestionClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Questions, Length(Questions) + 1);
  Idx := High(Questions);
  Questions[Idx].QuestionID := GetNextQuestionID;
  Questions[Idx].Question := NewQuestDesc.Text;
  Questions[Idx].Answer := NewQuestAns.Text;
end;
```